# Puppeteer can't distinguish between two selectors with same ID

Tags: puppeteer

I have a puppeteer implementation I'm working on to fill out a form on a website that (sadly) doesn't offer an API.

Everything goes great until I use this code to click the second button on a list of buttons:

```
await page.click('#calculateCharge'); // open the set values dialog
```

Reason being, the #calculateCharge id is used multiple times on the page, like this:

```
<button id="calculateCharge" type="button" name="amount" class="btn btn--secondary btn--full-mobile btn--full "><span>$ 80.00</span></button>
<button id="calculateCharge" type="button" name="amount" class="btn btn--secondary btn--full-mobile btn--full "><span>$ 35.00</span></button>
<button id="calculateCharge" type="button" name="amount" class="btn btn--secondary btn--full-mobile btn--full "><span>$ 42.00</span></button>
```

Puppeteer clicks the first button every time because whoever wrote the HTML didn't id the buttons dynamically.  The ids are all the same, so I don't know how to access the 2nd or third buttons.  I also don't have access to the HTML source (not my page), so I can't fix it from the other side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Those buttons appear to have all manner of other ways of accessing them -- their text, class, element name, index... I suggest picking one of those other ways that makes the most sense for your use case and using that.

Comment: that's the right direction!  see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using xPaths instead of ids.

First, right click on the button in your browser and click inspect. In the inspector's HTML tree, right click on the highlighted HTML and copy the *full* xPath.

Second, set the element as a variable using the copied xPath.  Note the `x` after the `$`.

`let butt = await page.$x('xPath')`

Last, click the button by referencing the first position of the variable's array.

`await butt[0].click()`

Copy/paste from my production file:

```
    let butt = await page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/div/div/button');
    await butt[0].click();
```